# How do I make similar principal component variables calculated using two different datasets comparable?

Tags: pca, econometrics

I am currently working with two separate datasets. The first one is the dataset available for the replication of results presented in some existing journal article (lets call that Data 1). The second one is a publicly available survey dataset (Data 2, say). Now, data 1 defined some variables using Principal Component Analysis (PCA). For example, it defined asset holding of a household by taking the first principal component derived from a set of asset variables  (number of bicycles owned, number of cellphones owned etc.). The Data 1 makes only that asset (pc) variable available, together with the definition on which variables they used to calculate that variable.

I am trying to calculate the same kind of pc using Data 2. In a way such that it is comparable to the same variable in data 1 (from a regression perspective). Now there are two problems:

1. For some variables (like say, material your house is made of) the scales are not properly defined in data 1. So that makes it hard to re-create the same variable needed to calculate the pc in data 2.
2. Even if the variables are defined in the same way, the factor loadings are going to be different based on the variation in the dataset I am working with.

In such a scenario, my question is: how do I make the pc variables comparable across these two datasets (from a regression perspective)? Or at least, what are the kind of tests I can potentially do to check for any biases?

Comment: Material of the house is not a quantitative variable, is it? You can't use it in classic PCA.

Comment: Does data 2 contain exactly the same variables (features) as data 1, except the "material"?

Comment: Yes, the material is a qualitative category variable. Data 2 contains the same information as data 1, just the scales may be different (like the qualitative categories).